# Зачем использовать метод asList() в данном примере?

Tags: java, коллекции

```
    ArrayList<Human> children = new ArrayList<>();
    Human father = new Human("Harry", true, 45, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(child1, child2, child3)));
```

1. При инициализации объекта аргументом передается new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(child1, child2, child3)). Зачем приводить к листу (asList), если это и так списочный массив?
2. При инициализации объекта передается ли часть new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(child1, child2, child3) в ArrayList children?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Что такое child1, child2, child3? Что такое Human?

Comment: `Arrays.asList`возвращает `List`. Если в конструкторе нужен `ArrayList`, то нужно его создать.

Comment: @КириллМалышев Наверное вопрос о том, почему нельзя использовать только `Arrays.asList(child1, ...)` или только `new ArrayList<>(child1, ...)` ?

Comment: Про первый случай я ответил, а для второго просто нет такого конструктора, чтобы его использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays.asList() - такую конструкцию используют для получения коллекции List из массива. 
Вы не показали класс Human, поэтому тут есть 2 варианта: 
1) в классе Human поле, которое инициализирцется последним аргументом приведенного конструктора, имеет тип ArrayList, а не List. В этом случае new ArrayList<>() нужен для того, чтобы преобразовать полученный из Arrays.asList() игтерфейс List в ArrayList, потому как последний является наследником List и поэтому сам в него никак не превратиться (автоматическое приведение типов возможно только класса-наследника к родительскому классу, но но не наоборот). В данном случае я бы изменил тип поля с ArrayList на List. Это правильно с точки зрения ООП и конструкций new ArrayList<>(...) не потребуется.
2) этот вариант наиболее вероятный. проблема в том, что Arrays.asList() возвращает неизменяемый List. Это значит, что при попытке добавит в него элемент вы получите исключение! посему, если в дальнейшем предполаогается изменять List, полученный от Arrays.asList(), его надо превратить в обычную изменяемую коллекцию. Поскольку List является интерфейсом и создать его экземпляр мы не можем, приходится создавать новый ArrayList и передавать в его конструктор результат Arrays.asList(). Так мы получаем обычную коллекцию, которую можно менять.